# TimerHandler's onTimePassed not been called

Tags: android, andengine

I am new to andEngine and trying to create a simple game using it, but got stuck at initial stage.

I am trying to create splash screen with simple animation using andEngine's TimerHandler, but seems that after registerUpdateHandler it does not execute onTimePassed.

below is my code

```
public void createScene() {
    System.out.println("***************");     
   registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(INIT_WAIT, new ITimerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
           System.out.println("onTimePassed");
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: I think you need to register it to the scene. Something like scene.registerUpdateHandler

Comment: @sandeep I am extending my class with Scene class

Comment: so CLASSNAME.this.registerUpdateHandler..? just in case.. and also..what might be the INIT_WAIT value..?